# What's this kind of graph called?

Tags: data-visualization

I have a kind a graph, I found it while googling "tree graph" though it doesn't look like a normal tree-graph. So I was wondering, is it also just called a "tree-graph" or has it a more specific name? I want to look up more info about them, though can't really search for it without a proper name.

[image: Graph]

Thanks a lot!

PS. I'm not sure if this is the correct place to ask this, if it's not, please direct me to the proper place. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google calls it a [Treemap](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/treemap) and provides several examples and an ontology. They define the treemap as follows:

> A visual representation of a data tree, where each node can have zero or more children, and one parent (except for the root, which has no parents). Each node is displayed as a rectangle, sized and colored according to values that you assign. Sizes and colors are valued relative to all other nodes in the graph. 
>   *Source: Google Developers / Google Charts*

Comment: Aha, a treeMAP. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

It's typically called a ["heat map"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_map) or "heat chart".

Answer (score 1):

That's a [Treemap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treemapping):

> Treemaps display hierarchical (tree-structured) data as a set of
>   nested rectangles. Each branch of the tree is given a rectangle, which
>   is then tiled with smaller rectangles representing sub-branches. A
>   leaf node's rectangle has an area proportional to a specified
>   dimension on the data. Often the leaf nodes are colored to show a
>   separate dimension of the data.